# How to remove empty parameters from params hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails 4 application I have this setup:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @invoices = current_user.invoices.search(params)
  end

  ...

end
```

---

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  def self.search(params)
    data = all
    data = data.where("number LIKE ?", "%#{params[:number]}%") if params[:number]
    data = data.where("total > ?", params[:minimum]) if params[:minimum]
    data = data.where("total < ?", params[:maximum]) if params[:maximum]
    data
  end

  ...

end
```

The problem is that I have a bunch of other GET parameters which are all part of the `params` hash. How can I remove the blank parameters from the URL so that I don't end up with URLs like:

```
/invoices?after=&before=&maximum=&minimum=&number=
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that when you submit the form, you don't want the empty fields to be submitted through the URL? If so, you might need to use JS to intercept the form and remove the blank stuff before submitting it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Put this after the hash:

```
.reject{|_, v| v.blank?}
```

Comment: Just for clarity: Where exactly would you put that code?

Comment: @Tintin81Use this code anywhere a call to params is made in the controller that you want to filter. e.g. `User.create(params[:user].reject{|_, v| v.blank?})` An even better usage would be inside of your model, either on the setters or as a callback method before save.

Answer (score 29):

### Rails 6.1+

Rails 6.1 added [`compact`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-compact) and [`compact!`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-compact-21) to `ActionController::Parameters` in order to remove `nil` values from `params` hash.

```rb
params.compact

params.compact!
```

Here is a [link to PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39312).

---

Rails 6.1 added [`compact_blank`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-compact_blank) and [`compact_blank!`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-compact_blank-21) to `ActionController::Parameters` in order to remove `blank` values from `params` hash.

```rb
params.compact_blank

params.compact_blank!
```

Here is a [link to PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/36412).

[Examples of `blank` values:](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F)

```rb
nil, '', ' ', [], {}, false
```

Answer (score 2):

@Marian13 's answer is correct. Just as a complement, before someone goes down the rabbit hole of parameter methods, the following is a sanity saver.
[image: nil_blank_empty]